# ERROR Failed to find flength file

Tags: perl

To fazendo um script de upload funcionando tudo certo, mas o upload não funciona. Dá este erro:

> Failed to find flength file

O cgi-bin/upload.cgi está abaixo:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my $TEMP_DIR = '/tmp/';
my $DATA_DELIMITER  = '<=>';
my $DEBUG_PERL = 0;
my $UPLOAD_ID = '';
$| = 1; 
use strict;
use CGI qw(:cgi);
use File::Copy;
use File::Path;
use IO::File;

# Makes %ENV safer
$ENV{'PATH'} = '/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin';
delete @ENV{'IFS', 'CDPATH', 'ENV', 'BASH_ENV'};

my %query_string = parse_query_string($ENV{'QUERY_STRING'});   # Parse query string
my $print_issued = 0;                                          # Track print statement
my $remove_temp_dir = 0;                                       # Track remove upload_id.dir

if(exists($query_string{'upload_id'})){
    # Check for tainted upload id
    if($query_string{'upload_id'} =~ m/(^[a-zA-Z0-9]{32}$)/){ $UPLOAD_ID = $1; }
    else{ &kak("Invalid upload id", 1, __LINE__); }
}
else{ &kak("Invalid parameters passed", 1, __LINE__); }

my $sleep_time = 1;                                                                 # Seconds to wait before upload proceeds (for small file uploads)
my $temp_dir_id = $TEMP_DIR . $UPLOAD_ID . '.dir';                                  # The upload dir appendided to the temp dir
my $flength_file = $temp_dir_id . '/' . $UPLOAD_ID . '.flength';                    # Flength file is used to store the size of the upload in bytes
my $hook_file = $temp_dir_id . '/' . $UPLOAD_ID . '.hook';                          # Hook file is used to store upload info
my $hook_handle;                                                                    # File handle used for hook file
my %uploaded_files = ();                                                            # Hash used to store uploaded file names, sizes and types
my %current_file_uploads = ();                                                      # Hash used to store current upload info
my %config = &load_config_file($TEMP_DIR, $UPLOAD_ID, $DATA_DELIMITER);             # Hash used to store config values loaded from the upload_id.link file
############################################################################################################################################################
#   The config values from the link file are loaded at this point. You can now access or set config values. eg.
#
#   $config{'party_on'} = "indeed";
############################################################################################################################################################

# Create a temp directory based on upload id
mkpath($temp_dir_id, 0, 0777) or &kak("Failed to make $temp_dir_id: $!", 1, __LINE__);

# Create flength file
my $flength_handle = new IO::File;
$flength_handle->open("> $flength_file") or &kak("Failed to open $flength_file: $!", 1, __LINE__);
$flength_handle->autoflush(1);
chmod 0666, $flength_file;

if(!$config{'found_link_file'}){
    # If fail to find upload_id.link file, write error to flength file and exit
    $flength_handle->print("ERROR" . $DATA_DELIMITER . "Failed to open link file " . $UPLOAD_ID . ".link");
    $flength_handle->close();

    die("Failed to open " . $TEMP_DIR . $UPLOAD_ID . ".link: $!");
}
elsif($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} > $config{'max_upload_size'}){
    # If file size exceeds maximum, write error to flength file and exit
    my $max_size = &format_bytes($config{'max_upload_size'}, 99);
    $flength_handle->print("ERROR" . $DATA_DELIMITER . "Maximum upload size of $max_size exceeded");
    $flength_handle->close();

    die("Maximum upload size of $max_size exceeded");
}
elsif($config{'cgi_upload_hook'} && $CGI::VERSION <= 3.15){
    # CGI.pm version must be greater than 3.15 to use an upload hook
    $flength_handle->print("ERROR" . $DATA_DELIMITER . "CGI.pm ver" . $CGI::VERSION . " does not support an upload hook");
    $flength_handle->close();

    die("CGI.pm ver" . $CGI::VERSION . " does not support an upload hook");
}
else{
    # Write total upload size in bytes to flength file
    $flength_handle->print($ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    $flength_handle->close();

    # Clean up upload_id.dir when the script exits
    $remove_temp_dir = 1;
}

# Give progress bar a chance to get some info (for small file uploads)
sleep($sleep_time);

# Set the max post value
$CGI::POST_MAX = $config{'max_upload_size'};

# Get remote address, user agent and server name
$config{'remote_addr'} = $ENV{'REMOTE_ADDR'};
$config{'http_user_agent'} = $ENV{'HTTP_USER_AGENT'};
$config{'server_name'} = $ENV{'SERVER_NAME'};

if($config{'cgi_upload_hook'}){
    # Create an upload hook file
    $hook_handle = new IO::File;
    $hook_handle->open("> $hook_file") or &kak("Failed to open $hook_file: $!", 1, __LINE__);
    $hook_handle->autoflush(1);
    my $hook_query = CGI->new(\&hook, $hook_handle);
}
else{
    # Disable private temp files
    CGI::private_tempfiles(0);

    # Tell CGI.pm to use our directory based on upload id
    if($TempFile::TMPDIRECTORY){ $TempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $temp_dir_id; }
    elsif($CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY){ $CGITempFile::TMPDIRECTORY = $temp_dir_id; }
    else{ &kak("Failed to assign CGI temp directory: $!", 1, __LINE__); }
}

# Timestamp start of upload
$config{'start_upload'} = time();

# Upload finished
my $query = new CGI;

######################################################################################################
#   The upload is now complete, you can now access post values. eg. $query->param("some_post_value");
######################################################################################################

# Delete the flength file
rmtree($flength_file, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $flength_file: $!");

# Close and delete the hook file
if($config{'cgi_upload_hook'}){
    $hook_handle->close();
    rmtree($hook_file, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $hook_file: $!");
}

#####################################################################################################################
#   IF you are modifying the upload directory with a post or config  value, it may be done after this comment block.
#   Note: Making modifications based on posted input may be unsafe. Make sure your posted input is safe!
#
#   eg. $config{'upload_dir'} .= $query->param("employee_num") . '/';
#   eg. $config{'path_to_upload'} .= $query->param("employee_num") . '/';
#
#   eg. $config{'upload_dir'} .= $config{'employee_num'} . '/';
#   eg. $config{'path_to_upload'} .= $config{'employee_num'} . '/';
#####################################################################################################################

# Create upload directory if it does not exist
if(!-d $config{'upload_dir'}){ mkpath($config{'upload_dir'}, 0, 0777) or &kak("Failed to make $config{'upload_dir'}: $!", 1, __LINE__); }

# Process uploaded files
for my $upload_key (keys %{$query->{'.tmpfiles'}}){
    # Get the file slot name eg. 'upfile_0'
    $query->{'.tmpfiles'}->{$upload_key}->{'info'}->{'Content-Disposition'} =~ / name="([^"]*)"/;

    # Store file slot name
    my $file_slot = $1;

    # Get uploaded file name
    my $file_name = param($file_slot);

    # Strip extra path info from the file (IE). Note: Will likely cause problems with foreign languages like chinese
    $file_name =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/;

    # Get the upload file handle
    my $upload_filehandle = $query->upload($file_slot);

    # Get the CGI temp file name
    my $tmp_filename = $query->tmpFileName($upload_filehandle);

    # Get the type of file being uploaded
    my $content_type = $query->uploadInfo($upload_filehandle)->{'Content-Type'};

    # Get base file name and extension
    my($f_name, $file_extension) = $file_name =~ (/^(.*?)\.?([^\.]*)$/);

    #############################################################################################################
    #   IF you are modifying the file name with a post or config value, it may be done after this comment block.
    #
    #   Note: Making modifications based on posted input may be unsafe. Make sure your posted input is safe!
    #
    #   eg. $file_name = $f_name . "_" . $query->param("employee_num") . "." . $file_extension;
    #   eg. $file_name = $f_name . "_" . $config{'employee_num'} . "." . $file_extension;
    ##############################################################################################################

    my $zero_length_file_pass = 1;       # Default to pass check
    my $disallow_extensions_pass = 1;    # Default to pass check
    my $rename_file_pass = 1;            # Default to pass check


        #Check for zero length file
        $zero_length_file_pass = -s $tmp_filename;

        if($zero_length_file_pass){
                # Check disallow file extension
                if($config{'check_disallow_extensions_on_server'}){ $disallow_extensions_pass = &check_file_extension($file_extension, $config{'disallow_extensions'}, 2); }

                if($disallow_extensions_pass){
                    $file_name = &normalize_filename($file_name, '[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-\.]', '_', 6, 48); 

                    # Check for an existing file and rename if it already exists
                    if(!$config{'overwrite_existing_files'}){
                        if(&file_exists($config{'upload_dir'}, $file_name)){
                            my $renamed_file = &rename_file($config{'upload_dir'}, $file_name);

                            if($file_name ne $renamed_file){ $file_name = $renamed_file; }
                            else{ $rename_file_pass = 0; }
                        }
                }
            }
        }

    # If all checks passed transfer file else record reason for failure
    if($zero_length_file_pass && $disallow_extensions_pass && $rename_file_pass){
        # Path to file and file name
        my $upload_file_path = $config{'upload_dir'} . $UPLOAD_ID;

        # Win wants the file handle closed before transfer
        close($upload_filehandle);

        # Transfer uploaded file to final destination
        move($tmp_filename, $upload_file_path) or copy($tmp_filename, $upload_file_path) or &kak("Cannot move/copy from $tmp_filename to $upload_file_path: $!", 1, __LINE__);

        chmod 0666, $upload_file_path;

        # Store the upload file info
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_size'} = &get_file_size($config{'upload_dir'}, $UPLOAD_ID);
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_name'} = $file_name;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_type'} = $content_type;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status'} = 1;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'} = 'OK';
    }
    else{
        close($upload_filehandle);

        # Store the upload file info
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_size'} = 0;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_name'} = $file_name;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_type'} = $content_type;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status'} = 0;
        $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'} = 'FAIL:';

        # Record why the file transfer failed
        if(!$zero_length_file_pass){ $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'} .= 'Zero length file'; }
        elsif(!$disallow_extensions_pass){ $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'} .= 'Disallow extension'; }
        elsif(!$rename_file_pass){ $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'} .= 'Rename file'; }
    }
}

# Timestamp end of upload (includes local file transfer)
$config{'end_upload'} = time();

# Delete the temp directory based on upload id and everything in it
rmtree($temp_dir_id, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $temp_dir_id: $!\n");

# Purge old temp directories
if($config{'purge_temp_dirs'}){ &purge_ubr_dirs($TEMP_DIR, $config{'purge_temp_dirs_limit'}); }

# Log Upload
if($config{'log_uploads'}){
    my ($sec, $min, $hour, $mday, $mon, $year, $wday, $yday, $isdst) = localtime(time());
    $year += 1900;
    $mon++;

    # Initialize log directory and file name
    my $log_day = $config{'log_dir'} . $year . '-' . $mon . '-' . $mday . '/';
    my $log_file = $log_day . $UPLOAD_ID . ".log";

    # Create log directory if it does not exist
    if(!-d $log_day){ mkpath($log_day, 0, 0777) or &kak("Failed to make $log_day: $!", 1, __LINE__); }

    # Create log file
    my $log_handle = new IO::File;
    $log_handle->open("> $log_file") or &kak("Failed to open $UPLOAD_ID.log: $!", 1, __LINE__);
    $log_handle->autoflush(1);

    # Write log file
    &write_uu_file($log_handle, %config, %uploaded_files);
}

# Redirect or output
if($config{'redirect_after_upload'} > 0){
    # Redirect file (upload id.redirect)
    my $redirect_file = $TEMP_DIR . $UPLOAD_ID . '.redirect';

    # Create redirect file
    my $redirect_handle = new IO::File;
    $redirect_handle->open("> $redirect_file") or &kak("Failed to open $UPLOAD_ID.redirect: $!", 1, __LINE__);
    $redirect_handle->autoflush(1);

    # Write redirect file
    &write_uu_file($redirect_handle, %config, %uploaded_files);

    # Append upload id to redirect url
    my $redirect_url = $config{'redirect_url'} . "?upload_id=" . $UPLOAD_ID;
    my $embedded_upload_results = $config{'embedded_upload_results'};

    print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
    print "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    print "parent.Uploader.redirectAfterUpload('$redirect_url', $embedded_upload_results);\n";
    print "</script>\n";
}
else{
    #####################################################################################################################################
    # No redirect
    #
    # All the config, post and upload values are stored on the following
    #
    # %config{"some_config_value"};
    # $query->param("some_post_value");
    # $uploaded_files{'upfile_1243474989347'}{'file_size'} ;
    # $uploaded_files{'upfile_1243474989347'}{'file_name'};
    # $uploaded_files{'upfile_1243474989347'}{'file_type'};
    # $uploaded_files{'upfile_1243474989347'}{'file_status'};
    # $uploaded_files{'upfile_1243474989347'}{'file_status_desc'};
    #
    # Note: Below is an example of output calling a javascript pop-up in the parent. This would also be a good place to output
    # a JSON or XML string containing all the relevant information.
    #####################################################################################################################################

    print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
    print "<script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">\n";
    print "parent.Uploader.showCGIOutput('Upload Finished', 1);\n";
    print "</script>\n";
}

exit();
######################################################## START SUB ROUTINES ############################################################


####################################################
#   Clean up the upload_id.dir and everything in it
####################################################
END{
    if($remove_temp_dir){ if(-d $temp_dir_id){ rmtree($temp_dir_id, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $temp_dir_id: $!"); } }
}

###################################
#   Write upload info to hook file
###################################
sub hook{
    my ($current_filename, $buffer, $bytes_read, $hook_handle) = @_;
    my $total_bytes_read = 0;
    my $files_uploaded = keys(%current_file_uploads);

    $files_uploaded--;
    $current_filename =~ s/.*[\/\\](.*)/$1/;
    $current_file_uploads{$current_filename} = $bytes_read;

    for my $file_slot (keys %current_file_uploads){ $total_bytes_read += $current_file_uploads{$file_slot}; }

    my $stat = $total_bytes_read . $DATA_DELIMITER . $files_uploaded . $DATA_DELIMITER . $current_filename . $DATA_DELIMITER . $bytes_read;

    $hook_handle->seek(0,0);
    $hook_handle->print($stat);
    $hook_handle->truncate($hook_handle->tell());
}

##########################
#   Check file extension
##########################
sub check_file_extension{
    my $file_extension = shift;
    my $config_extensions = shift;
    my $mode = shift;

    if($mode == 1){
        if($file_extension =~ m/^$config_extensions$/i){ return 1; }
        else{ return 0; }
    }
    elsif($mode == 2) {
        if($file_extension !~ m/^$config_extensions$/i){ return 1; }
        else{ return 0; }
    }
    else{ return 0; }
}

##################################################
#   Get the size of the ploaded file if it exists
##################################################
sub get_file_size{
    my $upload_dir = shift;
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $file_size = 0;

    if(&file_exists($upload_dir, $file_name)){
        my $path_to_file = $upload_dir . $file_name;

        $file_size = -s $path_to_file;
    }

    return $file_size;
}

##################################################
#   Check if a file exists
##################################################
sub file_exists{
    my $file_path = shift;
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $path_to_file = $file_path . $file_name;

    if(-e $path_to_file && -f $path_to_file){ return 1; }
    else{ return 0; }
}

##################################################
#   formatBytes($file_size, 99) mixed file sizes
#   formatBytes($file_size, 0) KB file sizes
#   formatBytes($file_size, 1) MB file sizes etc
##################################################
sub format_bytes{
    my $bytes = shift;
    my $byte_format = shift;
    my $byte_size = 1024;
    my $i = 0;
    my @byte_type = (" KB", " MB", " GB", " TB", " PB", " EB", " ZB", " YB");

    $bytes /= $byte_size;

    if($byte_format == 99 || $byte_format > 7){
        while($bytes > $byte_size){
            $bytes /= $byte_size;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    else{
        while($i < $byte_format){
            $bytes /= $byte_size;
            $i++;
        }
    }

    $bytes = sprintf("%1.2f", $bytes);
    $bytes .= $byte_type[$i];

    return $bytes;
}

##############################################
#   Rename uploaded file if it already exists
##############################################
sub rename_file{
    my $upload_dir = shift;
    my $file_name = shift;
    my($f_name, $file_extension) = $file_name =~ (/^(.*?)\.?([^\.]*)$/);
    my $rename_limit = 1000;
    my $new_file_name = $file_name;
    my $file_renamed = 0;

    for(my $i = 0; $i < $rename_limit; $i++){
        if(&file_exists($upload_dir, $new_file_name)){
            if($file_extension ne ''){ $new_file_name = $f_name . '_' . $i . '.' . $file_extension; }
            else{ $new_file_name = $f_name . '_' . $i; }
        }
        else{
            $file_renamed = 1;
            last;
        }
    }

    if($file_renamed){ $file_name = $new_file_name; }

    return $file_name;
}

########################
#   Normalize file name
########################
sub normalize_filename{
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $normalize_file_name_regex = shift;
    my $normalize_file_name_char = shift;

    # Remove whitespaces from the beginning and end of the filename
    $file_name = &trim($file_name);

    # Check the length of the file name and add characters if neseccary
    if(length($file_name) < 6){ $file_name = &generate_random_string(6 - length($file_name)) . $file_name; }

    # Check the length of the file name and cut characters if neseccary
    if(length($file_name) > 48){ $file_name = substr($file_name, length($file_name) - 48); }

    # Search and replace non-latin characters below. eg.
    # $file_name =~ s/é/e/g;
    # $file_name =~ s/ü/ue/g;
    # $file_name =~ s/ä/ae/g;
    # $file_name =~ s/ë/e/g;
    # $file_name =~ s/ô/o/g;

    # Search and replace illegal file name characters
    $file_name =~ s/$normalize_file_name_regex/$normalize_file_name_char/g;

    return $file_name;
}

##################################
#   Strict check of the file name
##################################
sub strict_file_name_check{
    my $file_name = shift;
    my $strict_file_name_regex = shift;

    if($file_name !~ m/$strict_file_name_regex/){ return 0; }
    elsif(length($file_name) < 6){ return 0; }
    elsif(length($file_name) > 48){ return 0; }
    else{ return 1; }
}

#############################################################
#   Strip whitespace from the begginning and end of a string
#############################################################
sub trim{
    my $string = shift;

    $string =~ s/^\s+//; # Trim left
    $string =~ s/\s+$//; # Trim right

    return $string;
}

###########################
#   Generate Randon String
###########################
sub generate_random_string{
    my $length_of_randomstring = shift;
    my @chars = ('a'..'z', '0'..'9');
    my $random_string;

    for(my $i = 0; $i < $length_of_randomstring; $i++){ $random_string .= $chars[int(rand(@chars))]; }

    return $random_string;
}

###########################
#   Parse the query string
###########################
sub parse_query_string{
    my $buffer = shift;
    my @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    my %query_string = ();

    foreach my $pair (@pairs){
        my ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);

        $name =~ tr/+/ /;
        $name =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;

        $query_string{$name} = $value;
    }

    return %query_string;
}

######################
#   Load config file
######################
sub load_config_file{
    my $temp_dir = shift;
    my $upload_id = shift;
    my $data_delimiter = shift;
    my $config_file = $temp_dir . $upload_id . ".link";
    my %config = ();
    my $config_handle = new IO::File;
    my $timeout_limit = 3;

    $config{'found_link_file'} = 0;

    # Keep trying to read the link file until timeout
    for(my $i = 0; $i < $timeout_limit; $i++){
        if($config_handle->open("< $config_file")){
            $config{'found_link_file'} = 1;
            my @raw_config =  <$config_handle>;
            $config_handle->close();

            foreach my $config_setting (@raw_config){
                chomp($config_setting);
                my($config_name, $config_value) = split($data_delimiter, $config_setting);
                $config{$config_name} = $config_value;
            }

            if($config{'delete_link_file'}){ rmtree($config_file, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $config_file: $!"); }

            last;
        }
        else{ sleep(1); }
    }

    return %config;
}

#################################
#   Purge old upload directories
#################################
sub purge_ubr_dirs{
    my $temp_dir = shift;
    my $purge_temp_dirs_limit = shift;
    my @upload_dirs = glob("$temp_dir*.dir");
    my $now_time = time();

    foreach my $upload_dir (@upload_dirs){
        my $dir_time = (stat($upload_dir))[9];

        if(($now_time - $dir_time) > $purge_temp_dirs_limit){ rmtree($upload_dir, 0, 1) or warn("Failed to remove $upload_dir: $!"); }
    }
}

##########################################################################
#   Write a XML file containing configuration upload and post information
##########################################################################
sub write_uu_file{
    my $file_handle = shift;
    my $config = shift;
    my $uploaded_files = shift;
    my @names = $query->param;

    binmode $file_handle;

    $file_handle->print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n");
    $file_handle->print("<uu_upload>\n");
    $file_handle->print("   <config>\n");

    # Write config values
    foreach my $config_setting (sort keys(%config)){ $file_handle->print("      <$config_setting>$config{$config_setting}<\/$config_setting>\n"); }

    $file_handle->print("   <\/config>\n");
    $file_handle->print("   <post>\n");

    #Write post values
    foreach my $key (@names){
        my @post_values = $query->param($key);

        foreach my $post_value (@post_values){
            $post_value =~ s/&/&amp;/g;
            $post_value =~ s/</&lt;/g;
            $post_value =~ s/>/&gt;/g;
            $post_value =~ s/'/&apos;/g;
            $post_value =~ s/"/&quot;/g;

            # Search and replace non-latin characters below. eg.
            # $post_value =~ s/é/e/g;
            # $post_value =~ s/ü/ue/g;
            # $post_value =~ s/ä/ae/g;
            # $post_value =~ s/ë/e/g;
            # $post_value =~ s/ô/o/g;

            $key =~ s/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_\-]//g;

            $file_handle->print("       <$key>$post_value<\/$key>\n");
        }
    }

    $file_handle->print("   <\/post>\n");
    $file_handle->print("   <file>\n");

    # Write upload file info
    for my $file_slot (keys %uploaded_files){
        my $file_name = $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_name'};
        my $file_size = $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_size'};
        my $file_type = $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_type'};
        my $file_status = $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status'};
        my $file_status_description = $uploaded_files{$file_slot}{'file_status_desc'};

        $file_handle->print("       <file_upload>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <slot>$file_slot<\/slot>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <name>$file_name<\/name>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <size>$file_size<\/size>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <type>$file_type<\/type>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <status>$file_status<\/status>\n");
        $file_handle->print("           <status_desc>$file_status_description<\/status_desc>\n");
        $file_handle->print("       <\/file_upload>\n");
    }

    $file_handle->print("   <\/file>\n");
    $file_handle->print("<\/uu_upload>\n");
    $file_handle->close();

    chmod 0666, $file_handle;
}

########################################################################
#   Output a message to the screen
#
#   You can use this function to debug your script.
#
#   eg. &kak("The value of blarg is: " . $blarg . "<br>", 1, __LINE__);
#   This will print the value of blarg and exit the script.
#
#   eg. &kak("The value of blarg is: " . $blarg . "<br>", 0, __LINE__);
#   This will print the value of blarg and continue the script.
########################################################################
sub kak{
    my $msg = shift;
    my $kak_exit = shift;
    my $line  = shift;

    if(!$print_issued){
        print "content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8\n\n";
        $print_issued = 1;
    }

    print "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd\">\n";
    print "<html>\n";
    print "     <head>\n";
    print "         <title>Upload<\/title>\n";
    print "         <meta http-equiv=\"content-type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\n";
    print "         <meta http-equiv=\"Pragma\" content=\"no-cache\">\n";
    print "         <meta http-equiv=\"cache-control\" content=\"no-cache\">\n";
    print "         <meta http-equiv=\"expires\" content=\"-1\">\n";
    print "         <meta name=\"robots\" content=\"none\">\n";
    print "         <script language=\"javascript\" type=\"text/javascript\">if(parent.frames.length!=0){parent.Uploader.showEmbeddedUploadResults();}</script>\n";
    print "     <\/head>\n";
    print "     <body>\n";
    print "         <br>\n";
    print "         <div style='text-align:center;'>$msg</div>\n";
    print "         <br>\n";
    print "         <!-- Called on line: $line -->\n";
    print "     </body>\n";
    print "</html>\n";

    if($kak_exit){
        sleep(1);
        die("Died on line $line");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ola. Pergunta simplista, o ficheiro existe? Imprimia o `$flength_file` depois do criar e confirme que o ficheiro esta no sitio.

Comment: Você tem mais detalhes sobre o erro? Por exemplo, em que trecho do código ele ocorre? Conseguiria criar um exemplo menor que reproduza o problema? Ver [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Ele só da esse erro e nada mais, Forcei o PHP a mostrar os erros mas ele não mostra. E O Ficheiro não existe.